# Stretch line to width of Itemstemplate canvas in itemscontrol

Tags: wpf, xaml, itemscontrol, itemtemplate, itemspanel

I have this code.  For some reason I can't get the contentpresenter to stretch to fill the width of the canvas.  Several of my attempts are commented out in the xaml.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MarkerLocations, Mode=OneTime}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding}" />
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="0" />
            <!--Setter Property="Width" Value="{Binding Path=Width, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Canvas, AncestorLevel=1}}"/-->
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>

    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <!--Rectangle Stroke="Black" Height="2" Stretch="Fill"/-->
            <Line Stretch="Fill" X2="2" Y1="{Binding Mode=OneTime}" Y2="{Binding Mode=OneTime}" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

I have a feeling I'm not understanding the context of the ItemContainters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to bind to the width of stretching objects you should bind to the `ActualWidth`:

```xml
{Binding ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Canvas}}
```

---

**Edit:** *This may not be necessary*

Canvases have the habit of not occupying any space at all unless you tell them:

```
  <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MarkerLocations, Mode=OneTime}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Canvas Background="Red"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                        VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
  </ItemsControl>
```

Setting its `Background` is a useful "layout-debugging" trick to see if its actually there. From there one of your approaches should work.

Comment: I tried that but my ContentPresenters still have a fixed width of 3.  The canvas width varies with the width of the window (using Snoop to inspect the control while it runs).

Comment: The binding in the `ContainerStyle` should be: `{Binding ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Canvas}}`.

Comment: Excellent.  I didn't need the alignment stretch, but i'll mark this as the answer since I assume someone will need that.

Comment: @mydogisbox: You are right, there was a problem with my "frame" in which i tested it, edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: I might be digging out an old thread, but I am doing something similar and what surprises me is how complicated it is in xaml... I mean all these <ItemContainerStyle> stuff, why does that even have to be there? Are there any good tutorials on that?

Comment: @DanielGruszczyk: I recommend reading the remarks sections of the respective classes and properties on MSDN. I never did any WPF tutorials, in that regard i would only recommend the dedicated [articles on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754130.aspx).