# Strech ListBox/ItemsControl in UWP

Tags: xaml, uwp, win-universal-app, winrt-xaml

I want to stretch a listbox horizontally and vertically in UWP. I tried some WPF solutions, but none of them worked. ([Stretch line to width of Itemstemplate canvas in itemscontrol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8016168/stretch-line-to-width-of-itemstemplate-canvas-in-itemscontrol))

What I tried:

```
<Page.Content>
    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <ListBox VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Background="Green">
            <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"></Setter>
                    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"></Setter>
                    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch"></Setter>
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"></Setter>
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="AliceBlue" />
                </Style>
            </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <ListBox.Template>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBox">
                    <ItemsPresenter  Height="252" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </ListBox.Template>
            <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ListBoxItem>asdf</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>asdfasdf</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>asdfsdf</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>34</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>as2df</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>asdf</ListBoxItem>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</Page.Content>
```

The result is the following:

[image]

How can I stretch a listbox in uwp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have Explicitly Set the `Height="252"`. That is the reason why it does not show up. Also you set the background of actual ListBox to `Green` but that is overridden by your `ItemsPanelTemplate` so `Green` doesn't show up.

Your final XAML should look something like below.

```
<ListBox VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Background="Green">
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="AliceBlue" />
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListBoxItem>asdf</ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem>asdfasdf</ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem>asdfsdf</ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem>34</ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem>as2df</ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem>asdf</ListBoxItem>
</ListBox>
```

This is not Tested but should work as you expected.

Comment: HorizontalAlignment and VerticalAlignment aren't necessary.