# Strech ListBox and ListBoxItems in UWP

Tags: xaml, uwp, winrt-xaml, uwp-xaml

I want to strech a ListBox with its **ListBoxItem**. Streching the ListBox itself isn't a problem. The problem seems to be, to tell the ListBoxItem to use the available space in the ListBox.

```
<Page.Content>
    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" Height="200">
        <ListBox VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Background="Green" ItemsSource="{x:Bind Path=ChessFieldList}" >
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate >
                    <StackPanel  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Background="Yellow" BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="3" >
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</Page.Content>
```

The image below shows the above and expected result.

[image]

How can I achieve the expected result?

[Edit] An other and in my opinion the correct solution: [Set Width and Height of ItemsControl Children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42448923/set-width-and-height-of-itemscontrol-children)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Strech ListBox/ItemsControl in UWP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40094115/strech-listbox-itemscontrol-in-uwp)

Comment: No thats regarding streching a listbox - this one regards streching listboxitems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common problem. All you need to do is set the `HorizontalContentAlignment` of the `ListBoxItem`s too:

```xml
<ListBox Background="Green" ItemsSource="{x:Bind ChessFieldList}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Background="Yellow" BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="3" Height="50">
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```

Since the `StackPanel` doesn't contain any content, it won't have any height, so I've just added `Height="50"` to it for the purpose of this demonstration.

Comment: I tried to replace the Stackpanel with a Grid, so that an explicit value for Height would be not necessary. But that seems not to work. Is there no solution without setting Height?

Comment: @Briefkasten A Grid without any child element has zero height.

Comment: @Clemens I used as DataTemplate:                     <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid Background="Yellow" BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="3">
                            <Border Background="Beige" CornerRadius="20"></Border>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>

Comment: A Border without child also has zero height (or a height of twice the BorderThickness).

Answer (score 0):

Simply add

```
<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    </Style>
</ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

If you use grouping, you should include:

```
<ListView.GroupStyle>
    <GroupStyle HidesIfEmpty="False">
        <GroupStyle.HeaderContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewHeaderItem">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
                <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
            </Style>
        </GroupStyle.HeaderContainerStyle>
    </GroupStyle>
</ListView.GroupStyle>
```

It's a bit more than you asked for, but it's a little-known technique.