# Set Width and Height of ItemsControl Children

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

My CustomItemsControl looks like the following:

```
   <local:CustomItemsControl x:Name="CustomItemsControl" >
        <local:CustomItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Border x:Name="rectangle" Background="Orange" CornerRadius="5"  />
            </DataTemplate>
        </local:CustomItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </local:CustomItemsControl>
```

Depending on the amount of the items which my CustomItemsControl contain, it should calculate the Width and the Height of "Container" Items.

I thought I could achieve that by calling the methods Measure/Arrange of the Items. But my Code doesn't seem to have any effects on the Item's size ((Actual)Width or (Actual)Height is NaN or 0)

```
public class CustomItemsControl : ItemsControl
{
    protected override Size MeasureOverride(Windows.Foundation.Size availableSize)
    {
        Windows.Foundation.Size size = base.ArrangeOverride(availableSize);
        if (ItemsSource != null)
        {
            double CellWidth = size.Width / Items.Count;
            foreach (var Item in Items)
            {
                DependencyObject Container = ContainerFromItem(Item);
                if(Container!=null)
                {
                    FrameworkElement Element = Container as FrameworkElement;
                    //Element.Width = CellWidth; 
                    //Element.Height = CellWidth; 
                    Element.Measure(new Size(CellWidth, CellWidth));
                    Element.Arrange(new Rect(0, 0, CellWidth, CellWidth));
                }

            }
        }
        return size;
    }
}
```

The items will not be displayed unless you set the Width and Height of the Border (e.g. 10). I try to accomplish that my CustomItemsControl calculates the Width and Height of the Items. What did I do wrong? How can I accomplish my plan?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write an appropriate custom `Panel` with overridden `MeasureOverride` and `ArrangeOverride` methods and assign it to the `ItemsPanel` property of an ItemsControl:

```
<ItemsControl>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <local:CustomPanel />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border ... />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

The `CustomPanel` class could look like shown below. The control arranges its child elements horizontally. It may be extended with an `Orientation` property like the one of StackPanel, to arrange its children either horizontally or vertically.

```
public class CustomPanel : Panel
{
    protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
    {
        var size = new Size();

        if (double.IsInfinity(availableSize.Width)) // availableSize may be infinite
        {
            availableSize.Width = RenderSize.Width;
        }

        if (Children.Count > 0)
        {
            var cellWidth = availableSize.Width / Children.Count;
            var childSize = new Size(cellWidth, cellWidth);

            foreach (var child in Children)
            {
                child.Measure(childSize);
            }

            size.Width = availableSize.Width;
            size.Height = cellWidth;
        }

        return size;
    }

    protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize)
    {
        var size = new Size();

        if (Children.Count > 0)
        {
            var cellWidth = finalSize.Width / Children.Count;
            var childRect = new Rect(0, 0, cellWidth, cellWidth);

            foreach (var child in Children)
            {
                child.Arrange(childRect);
                childRect.X += cellWidth;
            }

            size.Width = finalSize.Width;
            size.Height = cellWidth;
        }

        return size;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! How can I orientate the items vertical? With the above solution they are displayed vertical

Comment: Do you need to switch between two orientations?

Comment: Yes. btw. I figured it out by my self. I changed  `var cellWidth = size.Height / Children.Count;` and `childRect.Y += cellWidth;` :)

Comment: Ok, add an Orientation property, as StackPanel has. Note also that the edited code sample now returns the actual size of the arranged child elements, not `finalSize`. You would have to modify that code too for different orientations.

Comment: One more question. When I add a Stackpanel or Grid around the ItemsControl `<StackPanel><ItemsControl>...` it doesn't display anything because the `availableSize.Height` is set to `0`. How can I fix this?

Comment: You may set the HorizontalAlignment and/or VerticalAlignment property of the ItemsControl to Stretch. You also need to override the MeasureOverride method, see my edit.